# Does a function $f(x) = f''(x) \neq f'(x)$ exist?

Tags: analysis, derivatives

Or I mean a function that has the same integral and derivative, but not equal to them

$\exists f(x)\in \mathbb{C}: f(x) \neq F(x), f'(x) = F(x)$

or it's inherently impossible?
Is there an algorithm of solving, not like "hey, I know that this function exists, saw it somewhere" or "I just guessed"

Comment: $f(x)=\cosh(x)$ and $g(x)=\sinh x$ are both examples (you can also take linear combinations). These are the eigenfunctions for a certain linear constant coefficient differential operator; you get them by finding the roots of the characteristic polynomial etc. This is all explained in ODE texts.

Comment: Formatting note:  you could use MathJax in the title too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The equation $$f''(x) = f(x)$$ belongs to a class of ordinary differential equations that is entirely understood---linear, constant-coefficient, and homogeneous. Substituting the ansatz $y = e^{r x}$ (with $r$ some constant to be determined) in the equation gives
$$r^2 e^{r x} = e^{r x},$$
or
$$r = \pm 1.$$
Thus the only solutions of the equation of the form of the ansatz are $e^x$ and $e^{-x}$. A nice feature of linear, homogeneous differential equations is that any linear combination of solutions is again a solution. Thus, we get an entire $2$-parameter family of solutions, namely,
$$f(x) = A e^x + B e^{-x},$$
and it turns out that these are *all* of the solutions that are defined on all of $\Bbb R$.

Differentiating once gives
$$f'(x) = A e^x - B e^{-x},$$
so we see that $f'(x) \neq f(x)$ if and only if $B \neq 0$.

The solutions include the special functions $\cosh$ ($A = B = \frac{1}{2}$) and $\sinh$ ($A = -B = \frac{1}{2}$).

Comment: It is against the rules of MSE to answer a question without context.

Answer (score 2):

Two solutions are $$f(x) = \frac{e^{x}\pm e^{-x}}{2}.$$ This can be obtained by solving the differential equation $y'' = y$. This and similar equations can be solved with no *a priori* guesses on the functional form of the solutions, but it is somewhat complicated. It is more common to guess a particular form for a solution like $y = e^{rx}$ or $y=x^r$, substitute it into your equation, then determine what $r$ needs to be to satisfy the equation. This works because of solutions of differential equations like this are unique given the values $y(0)$ and $y'(0)$ in most circumstances, so any solution we find is guaranteed to be unique up to choice of initial conditions.

Comment: It is against the rules of MSE to answer a question without context.